# div content shows when display:none

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of divs that I only show after a certain action. Like a message for validation. For this one there are a couple of messages in one div, and I want them to be a couple of pixels apart. I know how to do it, but when I change the css you can see a part of the content without clicking the submit button.

With this code everything is okay, except I want the messages to be some pixels apart (padding-top: 5px or something) but when I do that you always see the padding I added, even on `display: none`.

My div:

```
<div id="fout"></div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
#fout
{
    display:none;
    margin-left:-75px;
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    background-color:#D73033;
    width:350px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro";
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

Here is my jquery just in case you need it:

```
 $(function(){

        // initialisatie formulier validatie. (validate.min.js)
        var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
            name: 'voornaam',
            display: 'Voornaam',    
            rules: 'required'
        }, {
            name: 'achternaam',
            display: 'achternaam', 
            rules: 'required'
        },{
            name: 'telefoonnummer',
            display: 'telefoon', 
            rules: 'required|numeric'
        },{
            name: 'email',
            display: 'email', 
            rules: 'required|valid_email'
        }], function(errors, event) {
            var berichten = document.getElementById('fout');
            $("#fout").css("display","none"); 
            $("#fout").fadeIn('slow').css;

            berichten.innerHTML = '';

            // als er fouten zijn:
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
                    berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
                }
            // als de validatie goed gegaan is:
            } else {
                var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
            var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
            var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            $.post('action.php',{action: "button", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam,    telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
                $('#result').html(res);
            });
        $('#insert').remove();


        $("#formpje").hide('slow').css;
        document.getElementById('goed').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';
        }

        // voorkom ten allertijde dat het formulier daadwerkelijk ge-submit wordt!
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have set :

```
    display:none;
    margin-left:-75px;
    display:block;
```

so `display:block;` overwrite `display:none;`

Remove `display:block;`

```
#fout
{
    display:none;  /* <-- 1st declaration */
    margin-left:-75px;
    display:block; /* <-- 2nd declaration which overwrites 1st declaration */
    font-size:15px;
    background-color:#D73033;
    width:350px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro";
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments by **abhitalks**

this is also a problem :

`$("#fout").css("display","none"); $("#fout").fadeIn('slow').css;`

**EDIT 2**

to give space between the lines, give :

`line-height:2em;` in your `#fout` class!!

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gHEVd/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Also, mention the problem with `$("#fout").css("display","none"); $("#fout").fadeIn('slow').css;`

Comment: Thanks, now my padding works, but when I add padding-top:5px it just gives padding to the edges, not to the messagetext. Any idea how to achieve that? And I need that extra display, none. It's weird but if I remove it from the style the padding shows. Now it's working how I want it to, only the message padding is wrong.

Comment: @Twan : please provide the fiddle!!

Comment: See that when you submit the form correctly you see a red bar, that is the padding space. Why is that showing when the display is none? All the other properties like width are not showing.

Comment: @Twan : you mean to say that space after the `submit` button is your cause of concern, its shouldn't be there when the form is not submitted...right???

Comment: @NoobEditor I got it to work now by deleting the fout div when the form is succesfully submitted. But what I want is the messages in the red box to be a little more apart from eachother. But padding-top:5px doesn't seem to work. The following messages: The Voornaam field is required.
The achternaam field is required.
The telefoon field is required.
The email field is required.

Comment: why don't you try `margin-top:5px` instead of `padding-top:5px` because `margin` would create space, `padding` will stretch the div only...so you won't see the effect in `padding`!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45264/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-twan)